# Reading Analog values of bluetooth module HC 05

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I am working on a project which requires signal strength of a bluetooth TX and RX. what i assume is that in bluetooth module like hc05, there is an antenna receiver which reads the analog signal and then passes it to its ADC to get data in terms of 0's and 1's. But is there any way i can read the analog signal strength of the reveiver antenna directly? Please help

Comment: Start by getting the data sheet for the HC05 and reading up on how it works. If anybody has written drivers for the HC05 you may also find useful information there.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking up the datasheet to see if there is a command for signal strength. It's impossible to **directly** read the the analog value since the signal strength is way too low in amplitude.